# python - Create sparse tiles in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I looked through the numpy documentation, but I don't know the exact terminology of the thing I want to do. I want to do the following:

```
a=np.array([[0,1,2],
[3,4,5],
[6,7,8],
[,9,10,11]])
b=np.sparse_tiles(a,(1,2),dtype=a.dtype)
b
array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,5],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,6,0,0,7,0,0,8],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,9,0,0,10,0,0,11]])
```

Is there anything built into numpy that can facilitate this? I prefer way of doing it without using loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.kron`:

```
>>> np.kron(a, [[0,0,0],[0,0,1]])
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0, 11]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Stepped slices do the trick:

```
In [210]: b=np.zeros((8,9),int)
In [211]: b[1::2, 2::3] = a
In [212]: b
Out[212]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0, 11]])
```